# Как убрать сообщение при старте от Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

При старте программы Windows Powershell всё время появляется сообщение с текстом:

```
Windows PowerShell
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

Попробуйте новую кроссплатформенную оболочку PowerShell (https://aka.ms/pscore6)
```

Как убрать это сообщение? Не нашёл в поисковике на это ответов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте аргумент `-NoLogo` при запуске powershell.

Comment: Подскажите, а как я могу запустить powershell с флагом -NoLogo? У самого файла вроде ничего нельзя изменить. Я бы хотел, чтобы powershell запускался с флагом -NoLogo везде, даже если я открываю терминал в VSCode, в котором указан powershell

Comment: @МихаилКамахин надо везде прописывать `powershell -NoLogo`

Comment: вместо этого я могу просто прописывать и clear, чтобы очистить консоль, но я хочу избавиться от прописывания, хочется чтобы оно само смогло работать